# copy array in a batch file

Tags: batch, xcopy, array

I have several files located across several directories/subfolders that I need to copy to several destinations.  I currently do this using xcopy but I do it line by line, so there are several lines of code.  A friend suggested that I use an array instead which is what I'm trying to do now.

I've tried several variations of getting this to work.  My last variation looks like this:

```
@echo off
set "mansource=somelocation\location1\sourcefolder"
set "mandest=someloacation\location2\destfolder

set src[0]="%MANSOURCE%\folderA\number1.pdf"
set dest[0]="%MANDEST%\folderB\number\1"

set src[1]="%MANSOURCE%\folderC\number2.pdf"
set dest[1]="%MANDEST%\folderD\number\2"
set /a "x=0"

for /r "%mansource%" %%f in (!src!) do xcopy "%%f" "!dest!" /v/y 
pause
```

So I know this is wrong since it doesn't work, but nothing else I've tried has worked either.  Every example I've found online so far about using arrays in a batch only has a "do ( echo" command to either list what is being indexed or print a statement to the cmd prompt.  I haven't been able to find any examples concerning an actual function like copying.  I did have a variation of the above code but it just resulted an infinite loop with "0 files copied" repeating forever.

The idea is to have the file in src[0] copied to the locations in dest[0], then the file in src[1] and so on.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Note: Using a *.pdf wildcard will not work as there are other pdf's in these locations and I only need specific ones to be copied.  Also, each file is in a different location from the next and each copy destination for that file is also different.

Comment: First thing that sticks out, you are missing a ending quote on line 3; is that a typo here, or in the actual code?

Comment: It's a typo here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are looking for a batch solution, another way to go about this is to create a [FOR](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) loop with the `0` thru `x` index range. The [FOR](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) loop will iterate the index number values and use the [CALL](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) command to call correlated subroutine names.

The subroutine label names will all be the same except the index number values (as in the [FOR](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) loop) are appended to the label names (i.e. `:idx0`, `:idx1`, `:idx2`, and so on).

Each subroutine should have the "same" variable names within but the values of each should be set accordingly for the need, but each subroutine must end with `GOTO :EOF`. The `GOTO :EOF` will pass control back to the caller and allow it to finish out it's logic so in this case the [FOR /R](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) loop will start.

Be sure to that once your logic ends, that you have it `EXIT` or `GOTO :EOF` so it does not move onto the logic beneath such as subroutine labels intended only to be executed with [CALL](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) commands.

### Example Script

```
@echo off

set "mansource=somelocation\location1\sourcefolder"
set "mandest=someloacation\location2\destfolder"

FOR %%A IN (0,1) DO CALL :idx%%A
for /r "%mansource%" %%f in (!src!) do xcopy "%%f" "!dest!" /v/y 
pause
::GOTO :EOF
EXIT

:idx0
set src="%MANSOURCE%\folderA\number1.pdf"
set dest="%MANDEST%\folderB\number\1"
GOTO :EOF

:idx1
set src="%MANSOURCE%\folderC\number2.pdf"
set dest="%MANDEST%\folderD\number\2"
GOTO :EOF
```

---

### Further Resources

- [FOR](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [CALL](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html)
- [GOTO - Jump to label](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)

Answer (score 0):

Batch + "arrays" (which are not actually arrays) are a pain. :)

I'd suggest using PowerShell instead, since it supports proper arrays.  Something like:

```
$mansource = "somelocation\location1\sourcefolder"
$mandest = "someloacation\location2\destfolder"

# Create empty arrays
$sources = @()
$destinations = @()

# Add values to arrays
$sources += Join-Path $mansource "\folderA\number1.pdf"
$sources += Join-Path $mansource "\folderC\number2.pdf"

$destinations += Join-Path $mandest "\folderB\number\1"
$destinations += Join-Path $mandest "\folderD\number\2"

# Iterate over the Sources array and copy to the matching Destination.
for ($i = 0; $i -le $sources.length; $i++) {
    Copy-Item $sources[$i] $destinations[$i] -Force
}
```

Comment: Yeah I thought of using powershell but I'd rather use batch for this particular purpose if I can.